# How to get only word between any link

Tags: php

Please suppose i have many link define in description.

```
$string = '<a href="http://www.google.com.pk/">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com.pk/">Facebook</a>';
```

i need only get Google and Facebook from string
Please help me

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to SO. [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) might be useful for this situation.

Concept:

```
$string ='<a href="http://www.google.com.pk/">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com.pk/">Facebook</a>';

$array = explode(' ',strip_tags($string));

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

[strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) is what you are looking for

```
$string = '<a href="http://www.google.com.pk/">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com.pk/">Facebook</a>';

echo strip_tags($string);
```

Output:

```
Google
Facebook
```

You can exclude tags that you dont want to remove

```
$string = '<p>Google</p><br />
<a href="http://www.facebook.com.pk/">Facebook</a><br />
<b>twitter<b><br />';

echo strip_tags($string,'<p><b><br>');
```

Output:

```
<p>Google</p><br />
Facebook<br />
<b>twitter<b><br />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply i have large number of text, in which img, paragraph and many other html tag if i user strip_tags than all html is remove i need only for links to unlink

Comment: @user3822721 according to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), you can feed the second parameter of `strip_tags()` of which tags you wanted to preserve, check the link